# Pandas - create data frame from nested key values and nested list in the dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary-comprehension

How to do untangle nested dictionary with list in key/value into columns? I tried different combination to solve converting nested dictionary into pandas data frame. Looked through the stack I am getting close to fix the problem just not quite.

Sample Data:

```
test = {
    'abc': {
        'company_id': '123c',
        'names': ['Oscar', 'John Smith', 'Smith, John'],
        'education': ['MS', 'BS']
    },
    'DEF': {
        'company_id': '124b',
        'names': ['Matt B.'],
        'education': ['']
    }
}
```

Tried:

1)

```
pd.DataFrame(list(test.items())) # not working entirely - creates {dictionary in col '1'}
```

2)

```
df = pd.concat({
        k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, 'index') for k, v in test.items()
    }, 
    axis=0)

df2 = df.T
df2.reset_index() # creates multiple columns
```

Output Needed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update:

With the release of `pandas 0.25` and the addition of `explode` this is now a **lot** easier:

```py
frame = pd.DataFrame(test).T
frame = frame.explode('names').set_index(
    ['company_id', 'names'],
    append=True).explode(
    'education').reset_index(
    ['company_id', 'names']
)
```

---

### Pre pandas 0.25:

This is not really lean but then this is a rather complicated transformation.
Inspired by [this blog post](https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-split-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-rows-in-pandas/), I solved it using two separate iterations of turning the list column into a series and then transforming the DataFrame using `melt`.

```
import pandas as pd

test = {
    'abc': {
        'company_id': '123c',
        'names': ['Oscar', 'John Smith', 'Smith, John'],
        'education': ['MS', 'BS']
    },
    'DEF': {
        'company_id': '124b',
        'names': ['Matt B.'],
        'education': ['']
    }
}

frame = pd.DataFrame(test).T

names = frame.names.apply(pd.Series)
frame = frame.merge(
    names, left_index=True, right_index=True).drop('names', axis=1)
frame = frame.reset_index().melt(
    id_vars=['index', 'company_id', 'education'],
    value_name='names').drop('variable', axis=1).dropna()

education = frame.education.apply(pd.Series)
frame = frame.merge(
    education, left_index=True, right_index=True).drop('education', axis=1)
frame = frame.melt(
    id_vars=['index', 'company_id', 'names'],
    value_name='education').drop(
    'variable', axis=1).dropna().sort_values(by=['company_id', 'names'])

frame.columns = ['set_name', 'company_id', 'names', 'education']

print(frame)
```

Result:

```
  set_name company_id        names education
2      abc       123c   John Smith        MS
6      abc       123c   John Smith        BS
0      abc       123c        Oscar        MS
4      abc       123c        Oscar        BS
3      abc       123c  Smith, John        MS
7      abc       123c  Smith, John        BS
1      DEF       124b      Matt B.
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I didn't knew it would this complicated. I thought either pandas/json dict library should be able to untaggle this kind of nested structured.

Comment: I've learned since yesterday that there is a `json_normalize` function that may be able to do this in a one-liner. I'll try and update my post if it works.

Comment: Oh yes tried `json_normalize` from pandas it didn't quite work. May be I used it differently.

Comment: @sharp I have edited my answer with a much better approach that has become available with `pandas 0.25`.

Comment: Thanks! This one so much shorter. The way I tried clearly didn't work, I didn't use `explode`.